# Spin-spin correlation in a non self-averaging system

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, simulations, correlation-functions

I'm having problems to understand how to compute the **spin-spin correlation** for my system in a Monte Carlo simulation.
As far as I know, the spin-spin correlation is defined as:
\begin{equation}
C(\bar{r}) = \langle  \bar{S}(\bar{R}) \cdot \bar{S}(\bar{R} + \bar{r})\rangle - \langle \bar{S}(\bar{R}) \rangle \cdot \langle \bar{S}(\bar{R} + \bar{r}) \rangle
\end{equation}
and if the system is **[self-averaging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-averaging)**, I can calculate it with only one big enough sample as:
\begin{equation}
C(\bar{r}) = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{R} \left(\bar{S}(\bar{R}) \cdot \bar{S}(\bar{R} + \bar{r}) \right) - \frac{1}{N^{2}} \sum_{R} \bar{S}(\bar{R}) \cdot \sum_{R} \bar{S}(\bar{R} + \bar{r})
\end{equation}
where N is the size of the sample.

But if my system is **non self-averaging**, it means this won't give me the right answer and that I have to average over different samples instead. Meaning:
\begin{eqnarray}
C_{R}(\bar{r}) &=& \frac{1}{\mbox{#samples}} \sum_{\mbox{samples}} \left( \bar{S}(\bar{R}) \cdot \bar{S}(\bar{R} + \bar{r}) \right) \\
&-& \frac{1}{\mbox{#samples}^{2}} \sum_{\mbox{samples}} \bar{S}(\bar{R}) \cdot \sum_{\mbox{samples}} \bar{S}(\bar{R} + \bar{r})\\
C(\bar{r}) &=& \sum_{R} C_{R} (\bar{r})
\end{eqnarray}

But this means that I have to save the values for $\bar{S}$ and $\bar{S}(\bar{R}) \cdot \bar{S}(\bar{R} + \bar{r})$ for every spin and every simulation in order to average them. Is this right? Am I understanding correctly this concepts? Is there another way -a simpler and more effective way- of computing $C(\bar{r})$ for non self-average systems?

Comment: Could you please add brief definitions of "self-averaging" and "non-self-averaging"?

Comment: Hi, @Deep! I added a link to wikipedia where these concepts are simply explained.